# Import of jar in IntelliJ is successful and imports are resolved but mvn clean install and package fails

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jar, pom.xml

Some classes in my spring boot maven project were showing errors on some imports , so I had to add an external jar dependency in my IntellIJ (Community) . After adding it all the errors are gone , and i can see the jar is listed inside external libraries in IntelliJ . I try to run the spring boot project , works fine . But when i try to do a mvn clean install or mvn clean on the project directory , it fails showing import errors on the same classes for which purpose i had added the jar . I tried re-building the project , invalidating caches , but issue still remains the same . I am not able to understand if adding the JAR has resolved the import errors , and project also starts , why mvn phases are having failure as if no jar is added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Maven based project you must manage project build configuration, including dependency management in Maven `pom.xml` build files, not adding it via IDE interface. So you need to add the required dependencies using the [Maven's dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) mechanism, simply inside Maven `dependencies` section. e.g.

```
<dependencies>
...
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

And by the way the [IDE helps you with that](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#generate_maven_dependency).